# Monodevelop on ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, monodevelop

I apt installed MonoDevelop `5.10.0.871-2` on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am not getting completions or cannot go to declarations. The main problem though is that the run/debug options are grayed out. Is it a normal behavior?

Comment: I've just created a strange solution. Too bad they have it as the default option and I didn't see what it does or does not. I wanted a Console application

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to build a version 6 latest, following the guide at
https://kvssoft.wordpress.com/2016/12/13/building-monodevelop-on-ubuntu/